# Android SQLite crashed after 170 row

Tags: android, sqlite

how to change this logic to work with more than 170 rows.

```
// Getting All test 
public List<Test> getAllTests(String str) {
    List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TESTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

   // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            //select rows by input string   
            if(cursor.getString(1).equals(str)){
                Test test = new Test();
                test.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                test.setTest(cursor.getString(1));
                test .setResult(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));

                // Adding test to list
                testList.add(test);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    //close database 
    db.close();

    //return list data     
    return testList;
}
```

I want to select all rows by input string. It logic work perfectly with 150 rows but after 160 work slowly and crash on 170 rows

Comment: Why don't you use a WHERE clause in your request ?

Comment: I try with Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE name =  " + str, null); but crashed

Comment: What is the crash you're seeing? From the description "after 160 work slowly and crash on 170 rows" would guess application not responding and in that case the problem is possibly elsewhere, or just that you're calling database code on the UI thread.

Comment: What is the name of your second column ?

Comment: Hello @Aleksandar Krasimirov

Comment: Names are id,name and result

Comment: @AleksandarKrasimirov, did you try my answer ?

Comment: @Kedarnath in you now give me cannot resolve symbol "were"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to change this logic to work with more than 170 rows?

```
// Getting All test 
public List<Test> getAllTests(String str) {
    List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
    // Select All Query

    //String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TESTS;
String selectQuery = "SELECT id,result FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " where name ='" + str + "'";
    // Now you are saving memory of one column. 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

   // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           Test test = new Test();
           // moved outside loop to prevent creating new object every time.
        do {
            //select rows by input string   
            //if(cursor.getString(1).equals(str)){
            // No need for if Codition any more
                test.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                //test.setTest(cursor.getString(1));
                test.setTest(str);
                test .setResult(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                // Adding test to list
                testList.add(test);
            //}
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    //close database 
    db.close();

    //return list data     
    return testList;
}
```

Comment: @ Kedarnath Thanks! Your work, of course slowly but work.(2 second/ 150rows and 13 sec/1500 rows )

Comment: @AleksandarKrasimirov, that's good to know. Since you are new to this site. Let me guide you how to accept an useful/right answer. Just tick to green tick mark besides the answer.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: MISPELLED METHOD

Use

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " WHERE " + your_id + " > " + String.valueOf(last_id) + " LIMIT 150";
```

as your query structure, and then keep track of the last row id like this`

```
int last_id;
do {
        //select rows by input string   
        if(cursor.getString(1).equals(str)){
            Test test = new Test();
            last_id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            test.setId(last_id);
            ...
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

every time the loop ends, just query again your db; the rows will be fetched from the next one you need, because last_id variable dinamically change according to your progress.

Comment: Note that, not knowing how you called your integer ID field, I used the ghost variable your_id; you should replace that with the actual column name in your DB.

Comment: It give me Cannot resolve method valueof(java.lang.String) and why you make this " LIMIT 150" ?

Comment: What is the name of your second column ?

Comment: @AleksandarKrasimirov there is no need for LIMIT, what is you stack trace seen on the logcat?

Comment: LIMIT 150 means you only fetch 150 rows at a time; you said there was no performance issue with getting those many elements, so it seemed a reasonable number limit for your Cursor object. Of course, you don't get all the rows in your DB like this, and need to query it again to fetch the next 150 rows. About the error, it is String.valueOf() with a capital "o". My bad for mispelling it.

Comment: LIMIT doesn't help much: you can easily fetch one million rows in one Cursor without any problems: just try it with a huge database and you will see

Comment: I am just answering the question as I can, pskink :) not knowing what the performance issues are about, I'm simply suggesting a workaround.

Comment: yes, i know, but it is still a workaround, not a fix of real problem

Comment: I know, that's what workaround means. If you have an answer, please post it; I'm sure that will be better then mine and will be awarded as a good one.

Comment: i asked for a stack trace but OP didn't answer ;-(, without that i cannot provide any right answer

Comment: How can I then? :) my answer is the best I could come up with given the circumstances, so I don't understand why you keep pointing out the obvious. If you don't like my answer, please just give your feedback through this site mechanisms; I'd rather loose reputation points than go off topic in the comments, hiding responses to Aleksandar and make it difficult for him to follow my thoughts.

Comment: @StG your logic work but too slowly 150 rows open for 2 seconds ,1500 rows for 15 second

Comment: Yeah, can't say it's a good answer, it just works! Perhaps you could try querying your DB in another thread? If your are unwrapping cursors into your MainThread, you are actually slowing down the entire Activity, resulting in poor performances. This way, you could have a responsive interface, filling up with items one by one! See the AsyncTask documentation on AndroidDeveloper, maybe it can be useful.

Comment: You're welcome :) hope AsyncTask works better, if it does can you please accept the answer?

Comment: @pskink I post logcat information in bottom of question

Answer (score 1):

Could try using same code differently in following way

```
// using sql query Differently
(SQliteDatabase) db.query(
    "TABLE_TESTS" / table name /,
    new String[] { "id", "result" } / columns names /,
    "name = ?" / where or selection /,
    new String[] { str } / selectionArgs i.e. value to replace ? /,
    null / groupBy /,
    null / having /,
    null / orderBy /
);
```

Another approach could be to use LIMIT and OFFSET to get data in parts to improve performance

```
// using LIMIT AND OFFSET 
public List<Test> getAllTests(String str) {

List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<Test>();
// Select All Query

            Integer count = 0;
            String countQuery = "SELECT count(id) FROM " + TABLE_TESTS;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            count= c.getCount();
            }
            db.close();

            int MAX_LENGTH = 150;

            if ( count > 0 ) {

                            int total_length = ( count / MAX_LENGTH ) + 1;

                            for ( int i=0; i<total_length; i++) {

                                            String selectQuery = "SELECT id,result FROM " + TABLE_TESTS + " LIMIT " + MAX_LENGTH + " OFFSET " + (i*MAX_LENGTH) ;

                                            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                                            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                               // looping through all rows and adding to list
                                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                                               Test test = new Test();
                                                               // moved outside loop to prevent creating new object every time.
                                                            do {
                                                                            //select rows by input string   
                                                                            if(cursor.getString(1).equals(str)){
                                                                                            test.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                                                                                            //test.setTest(cursor.getString(1));
                                                                                            test.setTest(str);
                                                                                            test .setResult(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                                                                                            // Adding test to list
                                                                                            testList.add(test);
                                                                            }
                                                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                                            }
                                            //close database 
                                            db.close();

                            }

            }

//return list data     
return testList;
}
```